# PHP check if variable got specific values

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

I´ve got a button and a in it variable from my CMS:

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $this->field('contact_person_mail#'.$elementCount)->value(); ?>">
```

Now I want, to check if the variable is a "http"(a webpage) of an email address and if so, add an "mailto:".

Can you guys help my with that?

Comment: "webpage of an email address"?

Comment: Yes, a check if the variable is a link to a webpage or an email address

Comment: There are several ways you can do this, what have you tried?

Comment: If tried it with "exist" but that was the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

> **[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)** — Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string.

```
<a href="<?php echo strpos($this->field('contact_person_mail#'.$elementCount)->value(),"http") !== false ? "" : "mailto:"; 
        echo $this->field('contact_person_mail#'.$elementCount)->value(); ?>
">
```

*Since, you haven't mention the name of that variable I am assuming that `contact_person_mail` could contain both URL or email.*

### UPDATE:

In case of ternary operator returns FALSE you don't need to echo anything. since your URL or email is already getting echoed after that. Ternary operator is only of printing `mailto:`.

Comment: So, can I change "$your_variable" to "$this->field('contact_person_mail#'.$elementCount)->value();"? Because that variable can have either a webpage link or email address?

Comment: So this would be right?
<a href="<?php echo strpos($this->field('contact_person_mail#'.$elementCount)->value(),"http") !== false ? $this->field('contact_person_mail#'.$elementCount)->value(); : "mailto:"; 
        echo $this->field('contact_person_mail#'.$elementCount)->value(); ?>
">

Comment: Check the updated code. in case of FALSE you dont need to echo anything. That's what is different in your code and mine.